# How to specify non-capturing groups for my regex to allow tags with dashes

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Well.. I would like to make a small change of a regex matcher inside the jQuery core in order to accomplish my goal: ***Allow matching tags with dash within the name***

Example: `<auto-link/>`, `<user-circle/>`, `<something-else></something-else>`

Today, jQuery tag matcher/regex is declared as `rsingleTag` variable, you can [see here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L58) on their source code, but it does not match what I need. So I came up with my modified change:

- Default regex: `/^<(\w+)\s*\/?>(?:<\/\1>|)$/`
- Modified regex with dashes: `/^<(\w(\w|-\w)*\s*\/?)>(?:<\/\1>|)$/`

So, the changes I made is matching perfectly, however when I try to extract strings from it using `rsingleTag.exec("<auto-link/>")` the result expected is not similar to the jQuery default regex.

- Default regex: `rsingleTag.exec("<div/>")` => `["<div/>", "div"]`
- Modified regex with dashes: `rsingleTag.exec("<div/>")` => `["<div/>", "div/", "v"]`

I would like the modified regex result to be the same as the default regex result plus allowing tags with dashes. What am I doing wrong or how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/^<(\w(\w|-\w)*\s*\/?)>(?:<\/\1>|)$/   - your attempt
/^<(\w[-\w]*)\s*\/?>(?:<\/\1>|)$/      - your intention
```

Comment: To answer your question, you could use `(?:\w|-\w)*` or `(?:-?\w+)*` (non-capturing group) instead of `[-\w]*`. This would be correct, since my solution allows tags like `<foo->`.